# Access secure RESTful url from another application

Tags: restful-url, jaas

Am using resteasy-servlet and secured url with JASS authentication 
eg:

```
<login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>WebSecurityDomain</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>Login.jsp</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>error.jsp</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>                                           
   </login-config>   
   <security-role>
        <role-name>
            SecurityAdmin
        </role-name>
    </security-role> 

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Secure Pages</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>SecurityAdmin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

Now if I want to access some url from above application using externa resource. Url response returns Login.jsp.

How can I authenticate and access url.

I have even tried SecurityInterceptor but its not even accessing this function.
eg:

```
public ServerResponse preProcess(HttpRequest request, ResourceMethodInvoker methodInvoked)
            throws Failure, WebApplicationException {
... 
return null;
    }
```

Comment: FORM-based authentication tends to target humans (browser users), as opposed to arbitrary (automated) clients. Either switch to a non-FORM-based authentication method, by means of which the client's credentials are sent as part of the request, or "teach" your client how to engage in an authentication dialogue with your service endpoint (*"request resource; if response requests authentication, supply credentials and submit that form; expect next response to be, or redirect you to, the originally requested resource"*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as am using FORM-based authentication I can't use rest calls from backend. To use rest call I need to pass SESSIONID which is generated inside Browser.

So am doing a POST call to login to service I need and after that if I use any call from Browser it automatically adds correct SESSIONID and let me use call